# Summing area depending on another field value in the Field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, area, summarizing

I have a landcover layer with an attribute of the administrative region (`"GEN"`). I am looking for an expression in the field calculator to calculate the summarized area depending on the GEN-field value.

I know I could do it with dissolve tool or with group stats, but I would like to have the `"GEN"` area sum as a field value in my attribute table.

[image]

Comment: Dissolve by name, calculate area, multi-to-single part, pole of inaccessibility, join attributes by location back to your original layer.

Comment: Ah, I found it. I need this expression: 

sum("area",group_by:="GEN")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just need to use that handy expression in the Field Calculator:

```
sum("area",group_by:="GEN")
```